# Templates In Kohana 3.1

Tags: templates, view, kohana, kohana-3

I used them before several months. Then I switched to Fuel. Then I switched back to Kohana.

Problem? I have forgot how to correctly use templates (with that I mean `Controller_Template`). There was [tutorials](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/tutorials/templates) on Kohana's docs, but now links seem to be broken.

Please remind me how to use them!

Comment: Some time has passed, but one thing in your post is interesting for me. Why have you switched from Fuel to Kohana?

Comment: Another interesting question is why ever try Fuel?

Comment: Well, I want to try all possible tools... I want to know them! For example, I'm using Python now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use them, you have to extend `Kohana_Template`. Then you would set a public field '$template' to your view name, and then just do $this->template->foo = "foo" to set variables on the template

```
public class Controller_MyController extends Controller_Template
{
    public $template = "my_view";
    public function action_foo()
    {
        $this->template->foo = "foo"
    }
}
```

But the core developers discourage people to use it. You could better use some kind of template engine like [Kostache](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache) to make up your templates.

Comment: just curious, why do they include it, if its usage is discouraged?

Comment: Because some people still use it I guess. Not sure though.

Answer (score -1):

```
$template = 'mytemplate';

function action_index() {
      $template->content = new View("content");
      $template->content->title = "page title"; // depends on the fields in your view
}
```

this will require that the mytemplate.php and content.php view files exist