# How To Start Using Kostache?

Tags: view, kohana, kohana-3, mustache

I just asked a question ( [Templates In Kohana 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245373/templates-in-kohana-3-1) ) about templates and now I know that I should use Kostache. It's a module for the [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com) template language.

Anyway, I just enabled Kostache module for my Kohana 3.1 and all works. It's installed correctly! What to do next? How to use it?

Where should I put my views now?
What my controller should extend?
How to assign variable?
How to make header, footer etc. for views?

Maybe there are step to step guide for it? [This](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache) and [this](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) won't help me a lot...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Where should I put my views now?

View classes contain logic for your templates and by convention should be stored in `classes/view/{template name}.php`

Templates contain your HTML and should be stored in the `templates` directory in the root of your module, e.g. `templates/login.mustache`

By default kostache will try and work out the location of the template based on your view class' name.

If your view class is called `View_Admin_Login` then kostache will look for `templates/admin/login.mustache`

> What my controller should extend?

You do not need to extend any special controllers, the normal `Controller` will work fine as a base.

> How to assign variable

Controller:

```
$view = new View_Admin_Login;

$view->message = 'Hello';
$this->response->body($view->render());
```

Template:

```
{{message}}
```

Of course, any methods or variables you declare in your view class will also be available in 
the template.  If there is a class variable and method with the same name then the method will always take precedence over the variable.

> How to make header, footer etc. for views

It will help if you read the [kostache guide](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache/blob/master/guide/kostache/usage.md). The idea is that your views extend [`Kostache_Layout`](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/kostache/layout.php), see also the [layout template](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache/blob/master/templates/layout.mustache)

Comment: That was easier than I thought... =]

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of demos and examples in both of the repositories that you said *won't* help you.

Comment: a step by step guide is the best way to get something work. "lots" of samples sounds like garbage sometimes and do not help at all. A clean sample helps a lot. Anyway thanks for the plugin, the idea is good to separate logic from the template. now I only need to learn how to use it.

Comment: I spent over a day trying to get Kostache_Layout to work and wasn't able to.  I finally found ddrake's kohana_demo on github which happens to use Kostache.  It was monumentally helpful. https://github.com/ddrake/kohana_demo

Comment: The ddrake repo was helpful (thanks), also found zombor's Vendo app (https://github.com/vendo/vendo), which is helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

//application/classes/controller:

```
class Controller_Test extends Controller {

 public function action_index()
 {
    $view = new View_Home;
    $this->response->body($view->render());
 }

}
```

//application/classes/view/Home.php:

```
class View_Home {
    public $name = "Chris";
    public $value = 10000;

    public function taxed_value() {
        return $this->value - ($this->value * 0.4);
    }

    public $in_ca = true;
    protected $_layout = 'home';
}
```

//application/templates/home.mustache:

```
Hello {{name}}
You have just won ${{value}}!
{{#in_ca}}
Well, ${{ taxed_value }}, after taxes.
{{/in_ca}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your APPPATH/classes/controller/Test.php:

```
class Controller_Test extends Controller{

    public function action_index()
    {
        $renderer = Kostache::factory();
        $this->response->body($renderer->render(new View_Test));
    }
}
```

In your MODPATH/KOstache/classes/view/Test.php:

```
class View_Test
{
    public $name = "Chris";
    public $value = 10000;

    public function taxed_value() {
        return $this->value - ($this->value * 0.4);
    }

    public $in_ca = true;
}
```

In your MODPATH/KOstache/classes/templates/test.mustache:

```
Hello {{name}}
You have just won ${{value}}!
{{#in_ca}}
Well, ${{ taxed_value }}, after taxes.
{{/in_ca}}
```

In the following example, do not pay attention to naming classes and inheritance:
[More examples on GitHub](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/tree/a448453da30c6862cad912cd3db4ac4b8751deb2/examples)